# What is the correct timestamp to use when querying GMAIL API by epoch

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

When making queries to the gmail API, I've seen 'unexpected' behaviour. More or less I want to cache the last run epoch value and then subsequently use the API query with paramater "after:{epoch}". I presumed that this field would be the "internalDate" (/1000) but this is incorrect and I can't find clear guidance in documentation.

Through trial and error of reading a payload and then querying I've found various other dates that gmail may use that seem to correspond to correct outcomes and would greatly appreciate confirmation on which google actually uses. There is:

payload -> headers -> name=["X-Received"] -> "value" (.... some very long text)

payload -> headers -> name=["ARC-seal"] -> "value" ("t=....")

payload -> headers -> name=["X-Google-DKIM-Signature"] -> "value" ("t=....")

There are a host of other times that are very similar but don't appear to be candidates based on testing. If someone also knows whether the query "after" is inclusive or exclusive // any rounding considerations that would be most appreciated also (my understanding is it's inclusive).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the value you are looking for is

payload -> headers -> name=["Received"]

Please keep in mind that there are a lot of header values called "Received" such as "Received-SPF" but also plain "Received" which are when each of the servers in charge of handling the email got it, email delivery infrastructure works by going through multiple servers, each has it's own purpose and is why you see so many received dates there.

The way you read those is by going from the first one (topmost) "Received" header which is when the server in charge of placing the email on your inbox received the message from there all the rest are hops from server to server but those happened before you even got the mail.

The other "Received" values there are for when the entity that handles your inbox received them, typically on a gmail you would see two "Received" headers with different information and possibly different dates/times but you have to remember that the one at the top is the one that more accurately depicts the moment when you can see the email on your inbox, this is better explained [here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643950/understanding-an-email-header).

Please keep in mind that you might see huge delays in comparison to other "received" type of headers, in the case of "Received-SPF" this means that the SPF checker received the email to then verify if the sender's SPF record allows for the email to be delivered in the recipient's inbox, this means that if the connection to the sender's SMTP server has a low quality the email might take a while to be delivered while both servers communicate so you should only trust the very first "Received" header.

To clarify, in practice, more often than not those dates and times are pretty similar as the delivery of emails is typically extremely fast but based on your request I believe it is an important

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I initially discarded that as this received flag is "Mon, 15 May 2023 08:06:45 -0700 (PDT)" which corresponds to: 1684163205. Querying after:1684163204 does not bring this result but after:1684163203 does. There are values for 1684163203 which is why I suspected those. Any ideas why this behaviour may exist?

Comment: That is definitely a weird behavior but I'm afraid I do not have a good answer for that one nor could I find anything in documentation... could you tell me which header shows 1684163203? maybe it has something to do with on which server the Gmail search happens?